# ros2 launch file was not found in the share directory

Tags: python, ros2, roslaunch

Using python in ROS2 and launching with:

```sh
ros2 launch package_name launch_file_name.launch.py
```

I get

> file 'launch_file_name.launch.py' was not found in the share directory of package 'package_name'

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure setup.py includes the correct launch files. Inside data_files in setup:

```py
(os.path.join('share', package_name), glob('launch/*.launch.py')),
```

Also import:

```py
import os  
from glob import glob
```

Comment: this doesn't work it should be `        (os.path.join('share', package_name, 'launch'), glob(os.path.join('launch', '*launch.[pxy][yma]*')))
`